# Is linear elasticity mathematics or physics?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I wonder if questions regarding linear elasticity are considered math or physics.

I started wondering when my post was closed without understandable motivation:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3966782/can-elongation-result-from-elastic-twist

Comment: Question about linear elasticity can be mathematical and/or physical. It depends on how the question are presented. In the question that has been closed, you are asking whether there are cases the "stress" part of the stiffness tensor $C$ is non-symmetric. You are making a query on something in  real world, so you questions falls into the physics side.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to improve my questions.